# Variable not getting initialised when using a function with completion handler

Tags: swift, scope, completionhandler, sendbird

I am trying to initialise variable `channels` with the number of chat channels that are available in my SendBird chat application. I use for this process a function called: `private func loadChannels()` in order to load the channels into that variable mentioned above. What I don't understand is that the channels are loaded when the function is called and can be displayed as you can see in the code below. However, when I want to display the content of the same variable `channels` outside of `loadChannels()` I get an empty variable. What can be the problem?

```
import UIKit
import SendBirdSDK
import JSQMessagesViewController


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var messages = [JSQMessage]()

    var channels =  [SBDOpenChannel]()
    private var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?
    private var openChannelListQuery: SBDOpenChannelListQuery?



    override func viewDidLoad() {


        //connecting to the application
        SBDMain.initWithApplicationId("1662A8E8-F45F-454B-9E5E-02362342ECC5")

        //Connecting the user
        SBDMain.connect(withUserId: "tahrisqalli", completionHandler: { (user, error) in
            // ...
            print("connected tahrisqalli")


                print ("printing channels")
                self.loadChannels()
                print (self.channels)


            print ("printing channels")
            self.loadChannels()
            // Here content of channels variable is empty 
            print (self.channels)

        })



    }

 private func loadChannels() {
        self.openChannelListQuery = SBDOpenChannel.createOpenChannelListQuery()
        self.openChannelListQuery?.limit = 20

        if self.openChannelListQuery?.hasNext == false {
            return
        }

        self.openChannelListQuery?.loadNextPage(completionHandler: { (channels, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print ("error")
                return
            }

            for channel in channels! {

                self.channels.append(channel)

            }
            // Here content of channels is full with the correct channels
            print (self.channels)

        })
    }
```

Comment: Since you're filling up the `channels` property in a completion handler, my guess would be that this handler is yet to be called (asynchronously?) when you reach the `print(...)` statement following the call to `loadChannels()`.

Comment: In that case where should I call it exactly?

Comment: There is no problem. Delete the `print` line after `self.loadChannels()` since – as dfri already mentioned – the method works asynchronously and this particular `print` line is meaningless.

Comment: If I want to use the 'channels' variable outside the function, how can I do it?

Comment: Put the code to *use the 'channels' variable* into the completion block, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import UIKit
import SendBirdSDK
import JSQMessagesViewController


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var messages = [JSQMessage]()

    var channels =  [SBDOpenChannel]()
    private var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?
    private var openChannelListQuery: SBDOpenChannelListQuery?



    override func viewDidLoad() {


        //connecting to the application
        SBDMain.initWithApplicationId("1662A8E8-F45F-454B-9E5E-02362342ECC5")

        //Connecting the user
        SBDMain.connect(withUserId: "tahrisqalli", completionHandler: { (user, error) in
            // ...
            print("connected tahrisqalli")


                print ("printing channels")
                self.loadChannels(){
                     print (self.channels)
                }



            //print ("printing channels")
            //self.loadChannels()
            // Here content of channels variable is empty 
            //print (self.channels)

        })



    }

 private func loadChannels(callback: @escaping () -> void) {
        self.openChannelListQuery = SBDOpenChannel.createOpenChannelListQuery()
        self.openChannelListQuery?.limit = 20

        if self.openChannelListQuery?.hasNext == false {
            return
        }

        self.openChannelListQuery?.loadNextPage(completionHandler: { (channels, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print ("error")
                return
            }

            for channel in channels! {

                self.channels.append(channel)

            }
            // Here content of channels is full with the correct channels
           // print (self.channels)
            callback()

        })
    }
```